# R - Tallying up number of new individuals encountered as days go by based on ID

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am monitoring an animal population. I have their individual IDs as numbers, the date they were encountered on, and the number of individuals encountered on that day. I want to sum up the total number of different individuals encountered as the days go by, so I need it to recognize same IDs and only add new individuals to the total encountered.

This is my dataset, the last column being my desired outcome:

```
Month Day   ID    N. individuals that day     Total encountered
5     13    44    3                           3
5     13    58    3                           3
5     13    57    3                           3
5     14    58    1                           3
5     15    44    2                           4
5     15    06    2                           4
```

Comment: Logic is not clear.  Why the number changed when 44 occured again while it didn't for 58

Comment: I think the idea is to look at each day and count the cumulative number of unique ID's seen up through that day.

Comment: @akrun it changed when 44 happened again because 06 was also encountered on that day for the first time. Notice since 2 individuals were encountered on that date,  N. individuals that day is 2 but Total encountered only increases by 1

Answer (score 1):

Edit - updated to working, but inelegant, solution. The process here was to use `padr` to create a row for every ID in every date, with a `1` once it appears. Then we can count how many IDs have appeared as of each date, and add that to the original with a join.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)

# First, make a date column for easier sorting etc.
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(paste(2019, Month, Day))) %>%
  select(date, ID) %>%
  mutate(appearance = 1)   # For counting later; if missing = NA in padded version

df2 <- df1 %>%
  padr::pad(group = "ID", start_val = min(df1$date), end_val = max(df1$dat)) %>%
  fill(appearance) %>%
  count(date, Month = month(date), Day = day(date), 
        wt = appearance, name = "Total_encountered_calc")

df %>%
  left_join(df2)
```

Output

```
  Month Day ID N_individuals_that_day Total_encountered       date Total_encountered_calc
1     5  13 44                      3                 3 2019-05-13                    3
2     5  13 58                      3                 3 2019-05-13                    3
3     5  13 57                      3                 3 2019-05-13                    3
4     5  14 58                      1                 3 2019-05-14                    3
5     5  15 44                      2                 4 2019-05-15                    4
6     5  15  6                      2                 4 2019-05-15                    4
```

Answer (score 1):

An option

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   add_count(Month, Day) %>%
   mutate(n1 = duplicated(ID)) %>% 
   group_by(Month, Day) %>% 
   mutate(n1 = c(min(n - n1), rep(0, n()-1))) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(n1 = cumsum(n1))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  Month   Day    ID     n    n1
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     5    13    44     3     3
#2     5    13    58     3     3
#3     5    13    57     3     3
#4     5    14    58     1     3
#5     5    15    44     2     4
#6     5    15     6     2     4
```